# Download .mhtml of webpage with Js?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mhtml, webarchive

I want to implement "save as mhtml" flag of chrome to simply download mhtml of a webpage on button click. Please help me.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I'm looking for the same thing

Comment: No, I could not figure it out precisely, but since My ulitmate goal was of printing the page, I invoked print dialog button on button click, and it worked for me.